# Save selected columns of a CSV file in a new CSV file

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv, writetofile

I've got a CSV file `input.csv` with 10 columns:

```
col0, col1, col2, ..., col9
```

I want to copy only specific columns, in this specific order:

```
col0,col5,col4,col7
```

into a new CSV file `output.csv`. How can I do that in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard library comes with a `csv` module for reading and writing CSV files.  With `itertools.imap()` and `operator.itemgetter()` is is trivial to select the wanted columns from the input and feed that result into the output file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
import csv
from itertools import imap
from operator import itemgetter


def main():
    delimiter = ','
    with open('input.csv', 'rb') as input_file:
        reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=delimiter)
        with open('output.csv', 'wb') as output_file:
            writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=delimiter)
            writer.writerows(imap(itemgetter(0, 5, 4, 7), reader))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

BlackJack's response is the way to go, use the `csv` module and since you know the index of the fields you want to output, you can reference and print them with command line output redirection to save them to a file when you execute the script `python process_csv.py > output.csv`

```
import csv
f = open(filename, 'rt')
reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
    print row[0] + "," + row[5] + "," + row[4] + "," + row[7]
```